# Sed swap patterns

Tags: sed, swap

My problem is to inverse 2 patterns in only one1 sed command.
Let's considered this text file :

```
LAYER M1
DIRECTION HORIZONTAL
END M1
LAYER M2
DIRECTION VERTICAL
END M2
```

So I want to invert HORIZONTAL / VERTICAL words pattern in one pass like this :

```
LAYER M1
DIRECTION VERTICAL
END M1
LAYER M2
DIRECTION HORIZONTAL
END M2
```

Comment: 1) can the HOR.. and VER... be in same line?  2) why the Question was tagged with "design-patterns" ??

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution to this over at unix.stackexchange - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21061/cleanly-swap-all-occurences-of-two-strings-using-sed

To apply it here would be:

```
sed 's/HORIZONTAL/VERTICAL/g; t; s/VERTICAL/HORIZONTAL/g' file
```

Depends on both VERTICAL and HORIZONTAL not appearing on the same line.

Comment: sed work per line so if the 2 term are not in the same line, it will occur not swap

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, this is not the case, the opposite is true! It will fail if both terms are on the same line. Please see the link for an explanation of the script.

Comment: your sed read only 1 line at a time so, cannot work if terms are on 2 different line. First test is true if you change any HORIZONTAL to VERTICAL (so there are only VERTICAL terms in the line) and go to end of action (so go and treat next line). If false, it change VERTICAL to HORIZONTAL so only HORIZONTAL are on this line.

Comment: sorry, cannot edit comment after 5 minutes. You are right it work for this sample due to alternative sequence and you do it perfectly, faster that using a temporary swap pattern. still sorry reading your sed too fast

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a proof, but I fear it is not possible in `sed` (If by "command" you mean sed commands like `s`, `i`, `b` etc.). It is possible with one command in Perl, though:

```
perl -pe 's/(HORIZONTAL)|(VERTICAL)/$1 ? VERTICAL : HORIZONTAL/e'
```

Comment: In fact, it was the ideal the solution but apparently, it's not possible with sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/day/temp/g' -e 's/night/day/g' -e 's/temp/night/g' infile
```

I don't know if sed can do multiple substitutions in one pass. The solution above sets every occurrence of day to temp, then in another pass night to day, and finally in the last pass temp to night.

Comment: I think it's the only solution with sed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n "N
   $ {
     s/HORIZONTAL\(.*\)VERTICAL/VERTICAL\1HORIZONTAL/
     t print
     s/VERTICAL\(.*\)HORIZONTAL/HORIZONTAL\1VERTICAL/
```

: print
         p
         }" YourFile

you need to first load all line in sed.

it work for your sample, if there is pattern border, code have to be modified to limit between pattern edge

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/HORIZONTAL/TMP/g;s/VERTICAL/HORIZONTAL/g;s/TMP/VERTICAL/g'
```

Comment: sed work per line so if the 2 term are not in the same line, it will occur not swap. Also first try there is no "TMP" in the string before, if not you will have a strnage behavior